# react function not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am rendering a react class using node js as so...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
module.exports = router;
```

The page gets rendered fine, but no function that I add gets called. For example, in my `App` class...

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
    }
    getClass() {
        return "a_class";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.getClass}></div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

The `getClass` function is not called. Instead the className becomes the code

```
class = getClass() {
    return "a_class";
}
```

instead of simply `a_class` when I check the html. For some reason, rather than the function being called, it is simply saved as a string and placed in to the className.

Why is this happening? I am not able to call any functions I make. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function isn't called because you didn't call it. You can see the function's source, because any function that gets coerected to a string will do the same (`(""+(foo=>bar)) === "foo=>bar"`). All you have to do is:

```
<div className={this.getClass()}></div>
```